# How to use valgrind analyser in Qt creator for static library project

Tags: c++, qt-creator, valgrind

I'm creating C++ project which will generate a static library as output and i will link this library for another application. I'm using Qt creator for creating static lib project and would like to use the valgrind and other analyzer tools available in Qt creator. How can i achieve this?.

P.S : command line check using valgrind/cppcheck tool also fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can only use Valgrind with executables - it is a dynamic analysis tool.

So you need to either test with your final application or else write some test harnesses which you can then run under Valgrind.